# Best way to create a div with Label: Textbox and have it nicely centered?

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

What's the best way to have the following?

```
Name:  [Textbox]
```

Inside a div? I find that the Name: part doesn't center nicely with the textbox, especially with a small font. I want the Name: part to be centered vertically.

In some cases, the left hand part can be quite long and wrap onto multiple lines, like this:

```
All known
addresses:   [Textbox]
```

Again, I would like the left hand part nicely centered.

I'm trying to stop using tables for layout, and move onto divs so I can do things properly, but I am having some issues. `style="vertical-align:middle"` doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You would get more views if at least one of the tags was about the context of your question. I don't think anyone is actively looking for the tag "align". But people willing to answer, say, HTML questions, may be looking for the tag "html". Or "css".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no *good* way to do this.  There's a decent writeup on some methods [here](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/), but most of them rely on hacking-around fixed-height elements, or using table/table-cell layouts on divs.

If having things centered is a hard requirement, I'd just [give up and use tables](http://giveupandusetables.com/)

Answer (score 0):

use tables or 2 divs: one for the label and another for your text box, so you'll be able to align them properly.

Answer (score -1):

HTML5 is giving us some pretty cool features to aid in these type of instances. Elements such as `<section>` and `<article>` can be quite useful depending on your circumstance.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_new_elements.asp

Comment: section or article are indeed nice things, but that's nothing to do with the OP questions'.

Comment: @MEM - yeah you're totally right. I don't know what the heck I was talking about. I'm going to delete this answer. Thanks!